# Mathematical calculation within \foreach loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

The minimal code below demonstrates the problem. The code as it is does not give the desired output. I assume the `\x-\y` is not being correctly handled. I have tried including braces, brackets, but to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 


\newcommand{\connection}[4][]{\draw[{#1}] (#2#3)--([yshift={#4cm}]#2#3) --([yshift={#4cm}]#2#3-|#3#2)--(#2#3-|#3#2)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% create the coordinates
\foreach \Lletter/\l in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
    {\foreach \Rletter/\r in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
        {\coordinate (\Lletter\Rletter) at ({\l+\r/10},0);}
}

% create the paths
\foreach \L/\x in {A/5}
{\foreach \R/\y in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
    {\connection{\L}{\R}{\x-\y};}
}

% this is the desired result
% \connection{A}{A}{5};
% \connection{A}{B}{4};
% \connection{A}{C}{3};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\foreach \L/\x in {A/5}
{\foreach \R/\y in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\result{\x-\y}
    \connection{\L}{\R}{\result};}
}`

Comment: Just in case you do know it: "an empty line, in the body, is a paragraph break" -thus you want to avoid empty lines for markup. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272926/empty-blank-lines-in-latex-code

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen In a `tikzpicture` spaces and empty lines usually don't matter (exception before the environment's optional argument, see Q41567). A nullfont is installed.

Comment: The problem is indeed the subtraction, as `#4` gets replaced by `\x-\y` and thus: `\x-\y cm` becomes `\x pt - \y cm`. Use either `(#4)*1cm` or, staying in the local coordinate system: `shift=(up:{#4})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [touhami said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308527/mathematical-calculation-within-foreach-loop-in-tikz#comment749300_308527), one way is to include an explicit call to `\pgfmathsetmacro` within the loop. However, since this *is* a loop, we might as well use the facilities provided by `\foreach` itself to evaluate variables using pgfmath expressions.

For example

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\newcommand{\connection}[4][]{%
  \draw [{#1}] (#2#3) -- ([yshift={#4cm}]#2#3) -- ([yshift={#4cm}]#2#3 -| #3#2) -- (#2#3 -| #3#2)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \Lletter/\l in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
  {\foreach \Rletter/\r in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
    {\coordinate (\Lletter\Rletter) at ({\l+\r/10},0);}
  }
  \foreach \L/\x in {A/5}
  {\foreach \R/\y [evaluate=\y as \z using {\x-\y}] in {A/0,B/1,C/2}
    {\connection{\L}{\R}{\z};}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: blocks]

Comment: Might also be a good idea to introduce OP to `count=\l from 0`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I assumed those were just examples, to be honest. Perhaps you're right, though.