# Space before and after align

Tags: align

I am curious if there is a "correct" way whether to add a space before/after the align:

```
Thus
(Should there be a space here?)    
\begin{align*}
\end{align*}
(Should there be a space here?)  
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary...
```

There is a clear difference between the two (in terms of spacing) and sometimes if I don't add a space after "\end{align*} there is a strange distortion.

Thanks for expert help.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example demonstrating what you're after?

Comment: If by "space" you mean empty line in the code, then no, you don't generally want that. More specifically it depends on whether the set of equations is at the end of a paragraph (in which case you want a paragraph break - empty line - after it) or inside a paragraph (in which case you don't want paragraph breaks anywhere).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never have a blank line before a display: TeX produces a spurious white line (a blank paragraph, not vertical space) in that case.

You need a blank line after the display if the following text is a new paragraph and don't need a blank line if it is not.

Comment: A blank line before a display will allow a page break, which is almost always a bad idea.