# How to insert spacing in my tex code without creating blank lines?

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

I want my tex code to look more transparent. For this I have inserted an enter between text and align environments. This creates an additional blank line in the pdf. What can I do so that no blank line is created?

Comment: Did you try adding `%` at the end of the text line? Feel free to add a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to your question to help everyone understand your issue.

Comment: Don't: a line with just `\begin{align}` in it is already a good visual clue.

Comment: white space in tex is not cosmetic pretty printing for laying out the source it is explicit command to produce output. A single newline is a space, a double newline is `\par`, end of paragraph.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309108 for more reasons not to put a blank line before a display.

Comment: @SebGlav thanks! This is really nice!